# Angular directive not getting info from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to write a directive to set the active classes to my header, which is shared all over my website, but for some reason it doesn't get the info from the controller.

Here's my directive

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.actions')
    .directive('header', header);

function header() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            var vm = this;
            vm.headerActive = 'none';

            vm.setHeaderActive = setHeaderActive;

            function setHeaderActive(item) {
                vm.headerActive = item;
                console.log(item)
            }
        },
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    };
    return directive;
}
})();
```

I'm setting it as an attribute correctly and I don't get any error messages.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: where's the template?

Comment: You don't need to inject $scope in your controller but we need to see the template.